# when await asyncio.sleep(0.01) is not enough

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

I have this program

```
import time
import asyncio


def is_prime(x):

    return not any(x//i == x/i for i in range(x-1, 1, -1))


async def highest_prime_below(x):

    print('Highest prime below %d' % x)
    for y in range(x-1, 0, -1):
        if is_prime(y):
            print('→ Highest prime below %d is %d' % (x, y))
            return y
        await asyncio.sleep(0.01)
    return None


async def main():

    t0 = time.time()
    await asyncio.wait( [
        highest_prime_below(100000),
        highest_prime_below(10000),
        highest_prime_below(1000)
        ] )
    t1 = time.time()
    print('Took %.2f ms' % (1000*(t1-t0)))


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
#loop.close()
```

that discovers prime numbers. You can see it here as well https://osf.io/w8u26/

My question is, lets say i have too many function calls

```
await asyncio.wait( [
        highest_prime_below(100000),
        highest_prime_below(10000),
        highest_prime_below(1000)
        #100 function calls here
        ] )
```

and i have only async slept this much `await asyncio.sleep(0.01)`

must all functions complete within the set time or will some functions be left undone when sleep time elapses?.

Comment: what is the purpose of using sleep there?

Comment: @Netwave allows the program to jump into next function do a little work then jump into the next

Comment: Yeah, I realize it was for making the async example have some async wait in each funtion.

Comment: @Netwave I do have that in my functions.

Comment: It is ok, because otherwise, those functions won't have any asynchronity.

Comment: @Netwave I dont think you understand my question.

Comment: yeah, I did not.

Comment: @Netwave Your answer was factually correct, it just didn't address the OP's confusion regarding the use of `asyncio.sleep()` in that particular program. (I'm not 100% sure mine does, either.)

Comment: @user4815162342 oh it does. i have even run the program with `await asyncio.sleep(0.01)` and `await asyncio.sleep(0)` and confirmed what you said in your answer. Thanks for taking time to answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> must all functions complete within the set time or will some functions be left undone when sleep time elapses?.

The amount of time you sleep is irrelevant; the only purpose `await asyncio.sleep()` serves here is to force asyncio to suspend execution to the event loop, and give other tasks a chance to run. You might also await `asyncio.sleep(0)` and you'd [achieve the same effect](https://github.com/python/asyncio/issues/284).

In other words: no, the run time of the functions is not in any way connected with the time specified in the sleep. As long as you are using `asyncio.wait()` to wait for all the coroutines, they will all have finished by the time `wait()` returns. Increasing the sleep time will only make them run longer.

Comment: Beware. `asyncio.sleep(0)` is not quite equivalent to `asyncio.sleep(0.000001)`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74493571/asyncio-sleep0-does-not-yield-control-to-the-event-loop/74498442#74498442

Comment: @TLW Good point. `asyncio.sleep(0)` is for situations where you want to yield to the event loop, so as not to hog it, but you don't  have a concrete expectation of what work has been carried out while you were suspended. `asyncio.sleep(0.000001)` might get you closer to knowing that a useful burst of work has finished (unless that code also uses a similar hack, of course). I would argue that both are anti-patterns used by beginners trying to port their non-async code to asyncio. Such sleeps can and should be avoided in favor of proper synchronization devices like async queues.

Answer (score 1):

This script is more cpu-bound than io-bound. Have you considered threading to achieve concurrency? You would see drastic improvements if you had to call hundreds of these functions.

Comment: I'm sorry to say but in the context of Python, this is actually not true. This boils down to the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL) in python preventing more than one thread to execute at the same time. You can read more about his here: https://realpython.com/python-gil/

Comment: Multiprocessing would be more effective because threads would be slowed down by GIL.

Comment: I think "concurrency" is [the wrong term to use here](https://go.dev/blog/waza-talk). The program already *is* concurrent in the sense that it has several tasks interleaving with each other. It's not parallel, though—I think that's what you meant.