# asyncio.wait_for() not raising TimeoutError with await asyncio.sleep(0.0)

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, python-asyncio

As i'm currently testing timeouts with `asyncio.wait_for()` I came across a behaviour that surprised me. In the code below

- `test_timeouterror_1` succeeds as expected
- `test_timeouterror_2` fails somewhat surprisingly

```python3
async def sleep_non_cooperative(
    sleep_blocking: float, sleep_before_return: float
) -> float:

    start = time()
    sleep_synchronous(sleep_blocking)
    elapsed = time() - start
    return await sleep(sleep_before_return, elapsed)


# this test succeeds as expected
async def test_timeouterror_1():
    coro_sleep = sleep_non_cooperative(5.0, 0.0000001)
    coro_wait = wait_for(coro_sleep, 1.0)

    with pytest.raises(TimeoutError):
        time_spent_in_coroutine = await coro_wait


# Failed: DID NOT RAISE <class 'TimeoutError'>
async def test_timeouterror_2():
    coro_sleep = sleep_non_cooperative(5.0, 0.0)
    coro_wait = wait_for(coro_sleep, 1.0)

    with pytest.raises(TimeoutError):
        time_spent_in_coroutine = await coro_wait
```

Basically i would have thought that the following holds true:

- When a coroutine has exceeded a timeout set with `wait_for(coro)`
- and it relinquishes control to the event loop after the timeout occured
- a `TimeoutError` will be raised at the `await` site

Now i understand that `await sleep(0.0)` takes a special shortcut, however it also explicitly states that it will:

> Skip one event loop run cycle.

Therefore i'm wondering if that is on purpose or if that's an implementation detail, where the `sleep(0.0)` shortcut schedules itself in front of any other possibly resumable callbacks (like timeout/cancellation invocation)?

Comment: As you suggest, this is due to an implementation detail.  You seem to have found another way of discovering the same thing as was discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74493571/asyncio-sleep0-does-not-yield-control-to-the-event-loop

Comment: I see. Thanks for the link, some good info in there.