# Scrapy spider skips pages and stops before end

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, python-asyncio, scrapy-playwright

I'm developing a spider with scrapy and Playwright to scrape a retail brand website. Basically, it's parsing all images of all colors of all products on all pages (page -> product -> color -> image). My problem is that my spider skips many products and stops crawling way before the end. In addition to that, it begins to scrape pages without having finished to scrape the previous ones and I don't want it to do that. Here is my code:

```
import scrapy
from connect_spider_db import DbSpider

class MySpider(DbSpider):
    name = "website"
    first_page = "https://www.website.fr/men/tshirts/"
    start_dicts = [{"url": first_page}]
    
    for k in range(2,150):
        start_dicts.append({"url": first_page + "?p=" + str(k),})

    def __init__(self, name=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(name, **kwargs)
        self.website = self.start_dicts[0]["url"].split("/")[2] # extracting 'www.website.fr'

        self.init()

    def start_requests(self):
        for start_dict in self.start_dicts:
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=start_dict["url"],
                callback=self.parse,
                meta=dict(
                    playwright=True,
                    playwright_include_page=False
                ),
            )

    def parse(self, response):
        css_selector = response.css('...').get()
        main_links = []
        for product in response.css(css_selector):
            link = product.css('a').attrib["href"]
            main_links.append(link)

        for product_link in main_links:
            yield response.follow(
                product_link,
                meta={
                    "playwright": True,
                    "playwright_include_page": True,
                    },
                callback=self.parse_product,
                )

    async def parse_product(self, response):
        page = response.meta["playwright_page"]
        links_list = []

        for product in response.css('...'):   # in all cases, the images of the current color must be selected
            image_url = product.xpath('@src').get()
            yield {'url': image_url}
        
        button = page.locator('button...')

        if await button.is_visible():
            await button.click()

        li_list = await page.locator('...Available colors...').all()

        for link in li_list:
            link_url = await link.get_attribute("href")
            links_list.append(link_url)
        
        for color_link in links_list:
            yield response.follow(
                color_link,
                callback=self.parse_color
                )
            
        await page.close()

    def parse_color(self, response):
        for product in ...:
            yield {...}
```

The button click corresponds to the display of all colors (not all displayed if there are more than 5). The imported class `DbSpider` is initializing a few things that don't matter in this simplified spider.

I've set `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 1`, I checked my CPU and it's not a memory problem.

This spider works when I keep only the first page, I would want it to begin to scrape the next page when it is done scraping the previous page. I think the asynchronous nature of scrapy requests is the problem.

I tried to begin with the first page and loop/click on the next page button but I ended with the same result. What could be wrong?

Comment: You are probably right about the issue being asynchronous.  I suggest using another web scraping framework.  Or just using playwright directly.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

In my log file I was getting these `asyncio` errors:

`Task was destroyed but it is pending!`

I managed to make them disappear by adding `asyncio.sleep(1)` before each `yield` statement. I'm losing speed but it works. I'm continuing my research but the understanding of `asyncio` really seems to be the key.

For anyone wanting more information on this `asyncio` syntax, I suggest going to [this excellent discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74493571/asyncio-sleep0-does-not-yield-control-to-the-event-loop).

### Update 2

The problem seems pretty deep, these `Task was destroyed but it is pending!` errors happen because Python only keeps weak references of tasks, which are randomly killed by the garbage collector. Here is the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/91887) corresponding to this serious problem.