# argument 1 has unexpected type 'float' with python version > 3.10

Tags: python, pyqt5, python-asyncio

Since Python 3.10 I've a trouble with **argument 1 has unexpected type 'float'** error when using asynqt asyncio.sleep functions whereas it was working well with Python 3.9

the code to reproduce is below and fails on the line **await asyncio.sleep(0.1)**. This works well with interger values. Was working with previous version of Python :

```
import functools
import sys, traceback
import asyncio, asyncqt
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow

# unknown exception handler
def handle_excepthook(type, message, stack):
    print(f'An unhandled exception occured: {message}. Traceback: {traceback.format_tb(stack)}')

class MainUi(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

async def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(True)

    loop = asyncqt.QEventLoop(app)
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

    await asyncio.sleep(0.1) # fails with float values

    ui = MainUi()
    ui.show()

    with loop:
        # Run the event loop until the UI is closed
        await asyncio.gather(loop.create_task(loop.run_forever()), loop.run_in_executor(None, functools.partial(ui.show)))

    # Cleanup and close the application
    loop.close()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        asyncio.run(main())
    except Exception as e:
        print("An error occurred:", e)
        traceback.print_exc()
        sys.exit(1)
```

this produces the error :

```
  File "C:\PLDesign\AntennaNoiseTracking\venv\Lib\site-packages\asyncqt\__init__.py", line 202, in add_callback
    timerid = self.startTimer(delay * 1000)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: startTimer(self, interval: int, timerType: Qt.TimerType = Qt.CoarseTimer): argument 1 has unexpected type 'float'
```

Any idea ?
Thanks
Stéphane

Comment: asyncio.sleep is supposed to support floats. But you're getting an error in asyncqt, so maybe it's more restrictive when you use the Qt event loop.

Comment: @Barmar Strangely though, I haven't found docs or an example using a float. Did you find a good example or article?

Comment: The documentation doesn't say, but there are other SO questions that use floats with no problem, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55782808/when-await-asyncio-sleep0-01-is-not-enough

Comment: The only issue they have is that the timer isn't precise enough for very fine intervals.

Comment: I've modified my example code to make it easier to understand. Works with Python 3.7, not with 3.11.
Actually this is a problem with asyncqt and python >3.10. asyncio.sleep always works fine with loop defined by asyncio like loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop) but when defining the loop with asyncqt it fails whereas I was used to do that before Python 3.10

Comment: found this link https://github.com/gmarull/asyncqt/blob/master/examples/executor_example.py of someone doing asyncio.sleep(.1) with asyncqt and his code doesn't work with python >3.10 as well, just tested...

Comment: I've manage to have it working by modyfing the __init__.py from asyncqt which is not desirale but is at least a temporarly workaround waiting an other nicer solution
so in __init__.py from asyncqt, line 202 you can remplace timerid = self.startTimer(delay * 1000) with timerid = self.startTimer(int(delay * 1000)). this will avoid the implicit casting from float to int that python > 3.10 complains for.
Anyone who has a greater solution please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While trying to contact the owner of asynqt I've figured out that it's not maintained anymore since three years.

You can use [QAsync](https://github.com/CabbageDevelopment/qasync) instead which is maintained and then replace asynqt by qasync while creating the event loop :

```
def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    loop = qasync.QEventLoop(app)
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
```

The on-the-fly casting from float to int is apparently corrected in qasync and the stuff runs perfectly now.